# Are CREATE INDEX statements replicated in row-based Mysql Replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

I've not been able to find a simple explanation of what kinds of statements are or are not replicated from a master db to a slave in MySQL, row-based replication.  Specifically I want to add a fulltext index to a table and am wondering if i'll have to do that on each slave too or if that will get replicated.

Comment: I _suspect_ it will be replicated, since there is no other way to get the index built on the slave.  It would be safe to simply try it; then if the FT index is missing on the slave, build it.  Probably all DDL statements go as SBR even if you are running RBR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DDL can still replicate with row-based replication

From the [MySQL Documentation for binlog-do-db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db)

> For example, DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE are always logged as statements, without regard to the logging format in effect

Since [**CREATE INDEX is mapped to ALTER TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html), `CREATE INDEX` will work just fine.

Comment: on master , i have fired create table , but it didnt replicated. i can see this command in binary log file but it is not replicated and replication has crossed the position of this statement